# Display specific values from array - Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, distinct-values

I'm trying to find a simple way to display specific values from an array. Here's a bit of background in the project and what I'm trying to accomplish.

**Background**

I dumped this array `{{ dd($stories) }}`:

```
Collection {#240 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    0 => Story {#241 ▼
      #table: "stories"
      #fillable: array:7 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▼
        "id" => 17
        "title" => "Some New Post"
        "slug" => "some-new-post"
        "category_id" => 8
        "is_draft" => 0
        "feat_image" => null
        "body" => """
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sagittis ipsum. Vivamus tristique, purus ut accumsan blandit, lorem turpis pellentesque ▶
          <p>Nulla nec dignissim odio. Curabitur sodales ullamcorper sapien ac tristique. Ut condimentum sodales sem, in pretium felis efficitur quis. Proin rhoncus a ips ▶
          <p>Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse nec nisl tristique, consectetur nibh et, sollicitudin ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc et mauris vehicula nibh rutrum viverra. ▶
          <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla auctor massa faucibus elit semp ▶
          <p>Maecenas congue mi sapien, eu dictum elit vestibulum quis. Aenean scelerisque iaculis turpis, sed dictum nisi lobortis at. Quisque justo ante, dapibus vel ia ▶
          """
        "excerpt" => "Some excerpt for all to see"
        "created_at" => "2017-02-12 23:00:35"
        "updated_at" => "2017-02-12 23:00:35"
      ]
      #original: array:10 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => Story {#242 ▶}
    2 => Story {#243 ▶}
    3 => Story {#244 ▶}
    4 => Story {#245 ▶}
    5 => Story {#246 ▶}
    6 => Story {#247 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I was able to set up the sql query to get the first seven (7) items where `'is_draft' = 0` using eloquent:

```
 $content['stories'] = Story::where('is_draft', '=', 0)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->take(7)
            ->get();
```

Now the problem is, I'd like to output data from this array statically. For example:

```
<span class="grid single">{{ $story[0]->title }}</span>
<span class="grid double">{{ $story[1]->title }}</span>
```

should output

```
<span>Some New Post</span>
<span>Another Post</span>
```

I'm not sure what the syntax is or how to set up the array to loop through and only display the items requested. I'm sure it has to requires a `foreach` loop and perhaps a `while` loop nested within. Just unsure of the syntax. Any ideas guys?

Comment: With the index being `stories` shouldn't it be `$stories[0]->title`?

Comment: @RossWilson This does work. I was able to use `$stories[0]->title`. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the correct list of items (I've called it `$stories` in this example), you simply need to loop over that list using Laravel Blade's `@foreach` directive:

```
@foreach ($stories as $story)
<span>{{ $story->title }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my original post. I forgot to add that I'd like it to iterate through the loop, and grab specific values and place them in different parts of my html page. In the example above, it'll be looping through all the stories and place the story data in a grid. The grid will have different classes added to it (not dynamically, although I am exploring the option), therefore a `foreach` one really work for me.

Comment: @sogen1us It's still not clear what you're trying to do. And doesn't `$stories[0]->title` work? If you are much more specific in your question, I may be able to help.

Comment: So the problem was, I was using the foreach. I didn't need to use it as @mopo922 suggested, all I need to do is refer directly to the item in the array. Thanks all!